# Why does the BN_bn2bin and BN_bin2bn not give me the same result if applied to an RSA key?

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, bignum

I m trying to create an RSA key  (has type BIGNUM) and then turn it into a char* in order to send it over a client-server channel and then turn it again into a BIGNUM again. The problem is, when I do the double cast I do not get the original result. I have tried to simulate the problem with another BIGNUM created by me, but it seems to have the problem only with the RSA key. Here is the code I used for the tests

```
RSA *rsa;

rsa = RSA_generate_key(2048, 65535, NULL, NULL);
if (RSA_check_key(rsa) != 1)
{
    printf("error");
}
const BIGNUM    *rsa_n = BN_new(), // modulul
    *rsa_e = BN_new(), // exponentul public
    *rsa_d = BN_new(); // exponentul privat
RSA_get0_key(rsa, &rsa_n, &rsa_e, &rsa_d);

//TEST 1
unsigned char* rsa_n_char = (unsigned char*)malloc(BN_num_bytes(rsa_n));
BN_bn2bin(rsa_n, rsa_n_char);
BIGNUM *rsa_n2=BN_new();
BN_bin2bn(rsa_n_char, strlen((char*)rsa_n_char) + 1, rsa_n2);
printf("%d\n", BN_cmp(rsa_n2, rsa_n)); // output -1 -> not equal

//TEST 2
unsigned char*test1_char = (unsigned char*)malloc(6);
test1_char = (unsigned char*)"apple";
BIGNUM *test1 = BN_new(), *test2 = BN_new();
BN_bin2bn(test1_char, strlen((char*)test1_char)+1, test1);

unsigned char*test2_char = (unsigned char*)malloc(BN_num_bytes(test1));
BN_bn2bin(test1, test2_char);
BN_bin2bn(test2_char, strlen((char*)test2_char)+1, test2);
printf("%d\n", BN_cmp(test1, test2)); // output 0 ->  equal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
BN_bin2bn(rsa_n_char, strlen((char*)rsa_n_char) + 1, rsa_n2);
```

The function `strlen` finds the length of a printable string by looking for a NUL terminator (0 byte). The data held in the buffer pointed to by `rsa_n_char` is not a printable string and is not NUL terminated. It is binary data - and may even contain the NUL (0) byte within it. You cannot use `strlen` for such data.

It happens to work in your second test because the binary data you are working with happens to also be a printable string.